# Disable pad click on 12.04 - driver problem?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

I'd like to disable pad click. Usually it was possible in system settings under `mouse and touch pad`, but in Ubuntu 12.04 I can't see "touch pad" in `mouse and touch pad` settings...

I've installed `touchpad-indicator` but it seems it's not what I wanted. I don't want to disable the touchpad, just the pad click.

Is it possible that the system lacks the drivers for the touchpad? How can I check it? I can't see the touchpad with system settings > mouse and touchpad (there is only "mouse"), with `synaptiks` nor with `pointing devices`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried synaptiks?
Although it says KDE, it works fine in Ubuntu.

[image: Install via the software center]

Under Touchpad configuration there should be some point "Tap" or similar (Sorry, I have the German version only), where you can set the mouse button that will be emulated by a tap.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I've installed synaptiks, but when I try to launch it, it says there is no touchpad or there is some problems with synaptiks drivers. But at the same moment, I have alert messages of system crash due to synaptiks... (`executable path /usr/bin/synaptiks`)...